# Not able to retrieve results from database in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using simple code to retrieve data from database table but not getting result it always shows "No Result found".
*Table Structure*
rollno Varchar(50) Primary Key,
name   Varchar(100),
fname   Varchar(100),
mname   Varchar(100),
course   Varchar(100),
duration   Varchar(100),
address  Varchar(100),
image blob.

HTML FORM CODE

```
<form name="input" action="q.php" target="display" method="post" >

                        Roll No: <input type="text" name="name">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {


$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.1freehosting.com","u890130056_certi","samsungk2","u890130056_certi");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rollno']);
{

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM certificate where rollno ='$name'");



 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['rollno'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['course'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['duration'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?> " height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}

}
else
{
echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>&nbsp;No Data Found , Please check your registration no. or contact the institute for clarification. &nbsp;".$line.'</td></tr>';
}




mysqli_close($con);
}}
?>
```

Comment: `rollno Varchar(50) Primary Key` Are you kidding ? Rollno is int Always

Comment: Hi Ankit once echo the query and check with db(i.e echo "SELECT * FROM certificate where rollno ='$name'";)

Comment: Heloo  , you really gave us **`YOUR DATABASE DETAILS ON   http://www.1freehosting.com/`** . THANKS . Edit your Connection details.Put dummy .

Answer (score 0):

```
name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rollno']);
```

where are you getting this 'rollno??
i dont get why are you saving the result by posting['rollno'] because the name of your feild is 'name'.

change this line

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rollno']);
```

to

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
```

Comment: and Also i won't be able to display image.could u plz help.

Comment: i think because you are not giving its base url to the image..
is this project build on localhost??

Comment: @AnkitSharma copy the url you get from the website and then check if there is a problem in the path of image..